# How do I get Japanese characters showing correctly in OpenOffice?

Tags: 10.10, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I get little squares for Japanese characters, even after installing a few Japanese packages like `openoffice.org-l10n-ja`, `language-support-fonts-ja`, etc.

Already tried logging off and restarting OpenOffice, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do installing full Japanese support help?

Look at the
*System / Administration / Language Support / Install-Remove Languages*:

[image: installing Japanese language support]

Don't forget to re-login — or else changes may not get applied.